# Traffic isseus when SSL is used

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate

We started to use SSL (urls stayed the same, but we went from http to https) and we see a huge cutback in traffic. Is there any change that this is related? And if so, how come?

Comment: Possibly, if there were automated bots and things visiting, they weren't https enabled?

Comment: Are you measuring traffic in requests or in bytes? It could just be compression.

Answer (score 0):

Most of your visitors won't be typing "https" into the browser, they'll just type your domain name (or, more likely, already have it in their history). You should keep a HTTP site that only contains a redirection to the HTTPS site.

Comment: Thanks, but we *do have* the redirect...

Comment: That wasn't immediately obvious from your question... Given that, I'd want to turn on a lot of SSL logging to see if there are any issues with SSL negotiation.